# PHP - Getting num_rows of different ID's without writing new statements?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, count

Basically, I'm coding a site that has many different categories and I want to display the amount of rows specific to that ID.

So for example, I have as the query:

```
$query= "SELECT job_sec FROM jobs WHERE job_sec = ?";
mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

I need to know how I can count the rows of an ID then echo the rows counted.

I'd like the results to display:

> Web Design: 2,001 jobs
>
> Logo Design: 5,120 Jobs

The job_sec column just uses a numerical value, would it be easier to have a text value then count the rows relating to the text value and echo them?

I have a feeling I need to use an array however I need the most efficient method.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In order to count rows, you might want to use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`. Try to work through a good tutorial: [http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming job_sec is the category and I think you are looking for "group by":

```
$sql= "SELECT job_sec, count(*) AS c FROM jobs GROUP BY job_sec";
$r = mysqli_query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
     echo $row['job_sec'] . ': ' . $row['c'] . ' Jobs ';
}
```

(didn't test and not sure if the mysqli syntax is correct)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however how can I define between the different ID's? For example, I was anticipating being able to echo something like "$row['21']" - 21 being the category number.

The way my site is setup at the moment, I have it displayed like this: "Accountancy jobs -  1"

I just need to echo the number of rows from that specific ID. Thanks for the reply mate!